# Contract method: Error: Provider not set or invalid

Tags: web3js, dapp-development

I'm building a Dapp using MetaMask. However, I'm getting an error when I try to call a method on my contract.

Here's the simplified code:

```
var web3 = new Web3(web3.currentProvider);
var contract = new web3.eth.Contract(contractData.abi);
contract.options.address = address;
contract.methods.getName().call().then(name => console.log(name))
```

This throws the following error:

```
Unhandled rejection Error: Provider not set or invalid
```

Digging through the debugger, it seems that the RequestManager doesn't have a provider set. However, I can't figure out how that provider should be set?

Comment: Try to add `var currentProvider = new Web3.providers.HttpProvider('http://localhost:7545');` and change first line to `var web3 = new Web3(currentProvider);`

Comment: `'http://localhost:7545'` be sure to change port if needed.

Comment: @RomanFrolov He's using MetaMask.

Comment: @DavidMihal Did you found a solution for this? I have the same problem.

Comment: @t_io Not really, but I've worked around the problem by calling `contract.setProvider(web3.currentProvider);` on each contract I create

Comment: could this be due to metamask not being installed?

Answer (score 2):

Have you set MetaMask to whatever test network you are using? If testrpc, select in Metamask that you want to connect to LocalHost 8545, and if using Ganache, you can create a custom RPC to connect to LocalHost 7545. From there, use the seed phrase given from testrpc or Ganache to "restore"/connect. This should pull in your accounts, and let you connect properly to a provider.

Comment: MetaMask seems to be working fine, I've been able to work around the problem by calling `contract.setProvider(web3.currentProvider);` on each contract I create.

The problem seems to be either a bug or confusing API with web3.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you haven't set the `from` address. 
Check out the [contract properties](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-eth-contract.html#properties). 
With MetaMask you can get the current selected address with `var account = web3.eth.accounts[0];`

If you add something like `contract.options.from = account;` it should work.